# Autocomplete city from database

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, collection, onepage-checkout

I want to create an autocomplete input for city in onepagecheckout, and registration form.

I've a database table with all my data and I've a function php tha give me the json that look like this

```
[{"comune":"Santa Brigida","provincia":"Bergamo","cap":"24014"}, {...},{...}]
```

In my php code I create a filter like this

```
 $comuniItaliani= Mage::getModel('comuniItaliani/comuniItaliani')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('comune', array('like' => $comuneCode.' %'));
```

But in this way the filter works only if a word is complete, i want to filter when the word start form:

ex. If I refer to the piece of json written obove:

```
> If I filter for "Santa" it work perfectly and gives me "Santa Brigida" 
but I want it to work even with "san" or "sant"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space char before the `%` in `array('like' => $comuneCode.' %')`.
So when you type in `san` the query will look like this:

```
Where ... AND comune LIKE 'san %'.
```

That's why it does not find anything, but it works when you type in `Santa`
`Santa Brigada` is matched by `LIKE 'santa %'`.
Just remove that space.

```
array('like' => $comuneCode.'%')
```